Print line with maximum number of words in a file, using awk
I intend to use 'awk' on a dummy file, to get the line with maximum number of fields/words in it - considering, I am using whitespace as "FS(field seperator)".
My dummyfile is as:
$ awk '{print}' awkexfile.txt 
This
is
an
example
file,
which
we
will
use
for
awk
actions


This is a seperate line in this file

This is a line, with comma - ,

This is a line, with

I am trying to print line
(and as a perk, also get the corresponding line number NR of that record).
awk '{if (length($0) > max) max = length($0)} END {if (NF == max) print NR $0}' awkexfile.txt
I was expecting an output like:
15 This is a seperate line in this file
I don't get any output for the above command.
I'm not sure, if once END is encountered by parser, does the awk parser get back to the line with NF == max

$0 is the whole line, if you want the number of fields why don't you use NF instead? And where does 15 come from in: I was expecting an output like: 15 This is a seperate line in this file ? That is the second line with 8 words.

Regarding "I'm not sure, if once END is encountered by parser, does the awk parser get back to the line with NF == max". No, the END section is simply executed once all input has been read.

please update the question with details on what to do if there are multiple lines with the same 'max' number of words/fields; display the first such line? display all such lines? display the last such line? something else?

@Thefourthbird - The 15th line in the file is: "This is a seperate line in this file"
I was trying to get "15" added as the first part of the printed output

@markp-fuso I have to confess, that's something I did not consider while posting the question.
I guess, according to my understanding, and the command I came up with - I am going to get the last line with "max" number of fields, and that's okay with me.

Your code prints nothing because NR at END is 5 (5 lines total in input), which is not equal to the number of chars in the longest line (36).  You want to get the line with the largest number of words/fields (not chars).  Try this:
'{if (NF>theNumberOfWords){theLine=$0; theLineNumber=NR; theNumberOfWords=NF}} END {print "line = <"theLine">,","line number=<"theLineNumber">,","number of words =<"theNumberOfWords">"}'


Thanks Andrew. Though this works, I am having a hard time understanding --
If I have not mentioned any explicit FS(default is whitespace), why would it consider every char as a separate field, and not every word?

"If I have not mentioned any explicit FS"-- irrelevant (what you mention does not effect how the code runs), ignoring.  "[FS] default is whitespace"-- agreed.  "why would it consider every char as a separate field"-- I do not know why it would do that in this context, and it is not doing that.  "and not every word?"-- This phrase, given the context of the sentence it is in, is basically equivalent to: "why would it not consider every word as a separate field".  Again, I do not know why it would do that in this context, and it is not doing that.  Rephrase the question, then I'll answer it.


if once END is encountered by parser, does the awk parser get back to
the line with NF == max

If you want to examine all lines first and then output those matching certain condition you might use so-called 2-pass solution, let awkexfile.txt content be
This
is
an
example
file,
which
we
will
use
for
awk
actions


This is a seperate line in this file

This is a line, with comma - ,

This is a line, with

then
awk 'FNR==NR{if (NF > max) max = NF;next}{if (NF == max) print FNR,$0}' awkexfile.txt awkexfile.txt

gives output
15 This is a seperate line in this file
17 This is a line, with comma - ,

Output has multiple lines as all of them have 8 fields, which is biggest value seen. Observe that awkexfile.txt appears as argument twice. Explanation: FNR is number of row in file, NR global number of row, therefore FNR==NR means when processing 1st file. If number of fields (NF) in current row is greater than max seen so far, then save it as max then go to next line i.e. do not do anything else. Due to next described earlier 2nd action is applied only to 2nd pass, if number of fields is equal to max found, then print number of row in file (FNR) and whole line ($0) sheared using output field separator (default is space).
(tested in GNU Awk 5.3.1)

Assuming you don't want non-word-constituent characters like - and , on their own to count as words and that if multiple lines have the same number of words you want all of them printed, this might be what you want, using any awk:
$ awk '
    {
        orig = $0
        gsub(/[^[:space:][:alnum:]_]+/, "")
    }
    NF > max {
        max = NF
        lines = ""
    }
    NF == max {
        lines = lines NR OFS orig ORS
    }
    END {
        printf "%s", lines
    }
' file
15 This is a seperate line in this file


$ awk '{count=0; 
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) count += ($i ~ /[[:alnum:]]/); 
        if (count>max) {max=count; linenum=NR; line=$0}} 
   END {print linenum,line}' file

15 This is a seperate line in this file

this will print the first line with the max number of words (containing at least one alphanumeric char). If there are more than one a two pass algorithm will be easier.
$ awk 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) count[FNR] += ($i ~ /[[:alnum:]]/); 
                if (count[FNR]>max) max=count[FNR]}                    
       max==count[FNR] {print FNR,$0}' file{,}

15 This is a seperate line in this file

